# Run-Time Check Failure #02, random number added to array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, runtime-error

I've written a little program that should sort an array. When I run it, it does its job but seems to add a random number to the array. I also get the error shown in the title.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void printArray(int nArray[], int nSize) {
using namespace std;
for (int jjj = 0; jjj <= nSize; jjj++)
    cout << nArray[jjj] << " ";
cout << endl;
}

void sortArray(int nArray[], int nSize, bool bPrint) {   // bPrint is used to wether print after every step or not

 for (int nStartIndex = 0; nStartIndex < nSize; nStartIndex++) {    // Durch jeden Teil des Arrays gehen
    int nSmallestIndex = nStartIndex;   // Den aktuellen Startindex als kleinsten nehmen

    for (int nCurrentIndex = nStartIndex + 1; nCurrentIndex <= nSize; nCurrentIndex++) {
        if (nArray[nCurrentIndex] < nArray[nSmallestIndex])
            nSmallestIndex = nCurrentIndex;
    }
    using namespace std;

    swap(nArray[nStartIndex], nArray[nSmallestIndex]);
    if (bPrint) {
        cout << "Swapping " << nArray[nStartIndex] << " and " << nArray[nSmallestIndex] << endl;
        printArray(nArray, nSize);
    }
  }

}

int main() {
    const int nSize = 7;
    int nArray[nSize] = { 3, 1, 5, 8, 2, 4, 6 };
    printArray(nArray, nSize);
    sortArray(nArray, nSize, true);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use std::sort().

Comment: `nCurrentIndex <= nSize` is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twice you have `<= nSize`, it should be `< nSize`.  In C++, if an array has size `N`, the valid indices are `0` through `N-1`.

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop condition is incorrect - should be `< nSize` rather than `<= nSize`. This explains why an additional random element is printed.

```
for (int jjj = 0; jjj < nSize; jjj++)
    cout << nArray[jjj] << " ";
```